# Adding focusable view to window manager without losing responsiveness on background

Tags: android, android-windowmanager

I have following problem:

I want to create a toolbar, with general setting for device (TV) by adding view to window manager. My toolbar is visible in the bottom of screen and it is an overlay on currently selected application. It has following parameters/flags:

- `WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT`
  -`WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_WATCH_OUTSIDE_TOUCH`
  -`WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE`
  -`WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL`
  -`PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT`

When I click on the toolbar it is working fine.
When I click on the background, toolbar is still at foreground, and background application is working fine.

The problem starts, when I am populating `ListView` from my toolbar. With those parameters, `onClick` and `onSelectItem` listeners are not working on that `ListView`. When I remove `FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE`, listeners start to work, but I cannot use background application any more. I have to close my toolbar in order to get focus on the background.

Do you have any idea, how to make both `ListView` and background application responsiveness?

Thanks in advance, for every answer/

Comment: Did you get this working?

Answer (score 0):

This is known issue with PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT, try PixelFormat.TRANSPARENT